# Webpack stopped working after refactoring: ERROR in Entry module not found

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Before I had the following webpack.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/index.jsx
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['static/dist']
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.jsx','.css'],
        alias: {
            '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query:{
                presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/preset-env'],
                plugins: [
                        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true }],  
                        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {'loose': true}],
                        '@babel/transform-runtime'
                        ]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/, 
            use: 'html-loader' 
        },
        {
            test: /\.md$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "html-loader"
              },
              {
                loader: "markdown-loader",
              }
            ]
        }
    ]}
};
module.exports = config;
```

Everything worked. After I decided to add environment variables into it I had to rewrite the content to:

```
module.exports = (env)=>{
  const envPath = env.NODE_ENV ? `.env.${env.NODE_ENV}` : '.env';
  const config = {
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/index.jsx
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['static/dist']
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.jsx','.css'],
        alias: {
            '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query:{
                presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/preset-env'],
                plugins: [
                        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true }],  
                        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {'loose': true}],
                        '@babel/transform-runtime'
                        ]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/, 
            use: 'html-loader' 
        },
        {
            test: /\.md$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "html-loader"
              },
              {
                loader: "markdown-loader",
              }
            ]
        }
    ]}
  };
  return config;
}
```

Now I have the following error:

```
Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.


ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'D:\path'
resolve './src' in 'D:\path'
```

Why now is it not working and how to fix it?

The index.jsx is in path/src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I forgot I used merging configs so I have a webpack.dev.js which has the following line:

```
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
```

And after the refactoring, as the webpack.common.js returns the function instead of the object the line should be changed to:

```
const common = require('./webpack.common.js')();
```